# How to read a command line parameter given to an uninstaller?

Tags: installation, nsis, uninstallation

Using NSIS, how can I read a (optional) command-line parameter provided to an uninstaller?

I don't need to read it by name-- just reading the first parameter given could be enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [GetParameters](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixE.html#E.1.11) and GetOptions helper functions in FileFunc.nsh (Included with NSIS)

Answer (score 12):

For anyone else's benefit, here's the actual code I used.

Program executed with parameter:

```
C:\path\to\program.exe -SELECT-DATA=FALSE
```

Then inside the uninstaller's `un.onInit` method:

```
Function un.onInit
  ${GetParameters} $R0
  ${GetOptions} $R0 "-SELECT-DATA=" $R1
  MessageBox MB_OK "Value read: $R1"
FunctionEnd
```

Will pop up a message box with the value: FALSE